# Value too long for column - error persisting LocalDate

Tags: java, hibernate, date, java-8

I am getting the following error while persisting a LocalDate field [Using VARCHAR(20) type in column]:

```
Value too long for column "BIRTH_DATE VARCHAR(20)":"'aced00057372000d6a6176612e74696d652e536572955d84ba1b2248b20c00007870770703000007e2060c78' (88)";
```

The field definition is as follows:

```
@Column(name = "BIRTH_DATE")
private LocalDate date;
@Column(name = "BIRTH_TIME")
private LocalTime time;
```

I am using spring data starter (1.5.9.RELEASE). Which internally uses hibernate 5.0.12.

According to the blogpost https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/

Hibernate 5, supports Java 8 features (DateTime API) out of the box. So, why this error is coming.

I have checked, and a valid LocalDate object is being created in run time. But the error is thrown while persisting. Here is the debug screenshot just before the call to `save()`
[image]

The error changes to the following, if I change column type to DATE:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: aced00057372000d6a6176612e74696d652e536572955d84ba1b2248b20c00007870770703000007e2060c78
    at org.h2.util.DateTimeUtils.parseDateValue(DateTimeUtils.java:313) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
```

Comment: It seems like your BIRTH_DATE column is a varchar in the DB. Could you confirm that?

Comment: Ya. But even after changing it to date type. the error persists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string you’ve encountered is the hexadecimal representation of a serialized object, which can be verified easily:

```
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new BigInteger(
    "aced00057372000d6a6176612e74696d652e536572955d84ba1b2248b20c00007870770703000007e2060c78", 16)
      .toByteArray());
is.read();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
final Object obj = ois.readObject();
System.out.println(obj+" ("+obj.getClass().getName()+')');
```

```
2018-06-12 (java.time.LocalDate)
```

Of course, storing a `LocalDate` as such a blob is not a sign of a genuine DateTime API support, as that should be the last resort for storing a value. Either, there is no support or it has not been properly configured. In either case, you have to recheck the environment.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. An out of context question here: Can we verify any hexadecimal representation of data in the above way? For example can we retrieve a String which is passed through SHA?

Comment: No, SHA provides a hash value that doesn’t allow to reconstruct the original data, but can be verified, if you have the original data (by hashing them on your machine too and comparing the hashes). I could only identify the specific data of your question as serialized data, because I’ve seed the `aced` marker before, which is the hex representation of [`ObjectStreamConstants.STREAM_MAGIC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.io.ObjectStreamConstants.STREAM_MAGIC)…

Comment: Thanks for the info holger. And for future reference:  The error got resolved upon adding hibernate-java8.jar dependency. So, it was a problem with the framework.

Comment: @Holger fantastic answer in its simplicity!